# Finding the reason for segmentation fault on debian system

Tags: debian, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We've recently set up a new test server (*debian*) and wish to run our application. The application starts just fine, but whenever I try to login through my application, or register a new user, I keep getting a segmentation fault.

As I'm no expert on debian or other linux systems, it's quite difficult for me to find the error. With logging I narrowed it down, so I know that it crashes just before an HTTP request sent to another API.

Is there any way for me to get a stacktrace, since it has something to do with the application?

Comment: You can try to catch the exception in your application and log all information from exception, including stack trace.

Comment: I do have a try/catch, but I'm not hitting the exception. It still just gives me the segfault.

Comment: Segfault is an unhandled exception.

Comment: Well I don't know what to do. I'm catching all exceptions `try { } catch (Exception e) { } `

Comment: run it through a debugger, like gdb?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with linux systems, could you perhaps explain the `gdb` commands? I'm not sure `gdb` is even installed on the server

Comment: @umläute According to GDB themselves, they don't support C# (https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: have you tried it? and I wouldn't expect a server to have *any* development tools installed by default (for security reasons; and also because the software on the server shouldn't need it anyhow), so you'll have to install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is not silver bullet here.  So you can try two approaches:

- Use Linux utilites (`gdb`, `pstack`, `strace`), but as I see you are new in Linux and it can be difficult for you.
- Try to use logging in your code to get the point in your code which cause the segfault. Using logging you can find the line of code in your application and all the parameters.  Having this information you will be able to get next investigation: check the permissions, installing library and so on.

Comment: I already did log my way through the application, which is how I know that it has something to do with an HTTP client request to an external API

Comment: If you show us the code it will be much easier to find the reason. Does the user have permission to establish network connection ?